# mongoose document saving is slower than expected, potentially nodejs javascript closure related

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mongodb, mongoose

I'm profiling a web app I wrote. Part of profiling involves generating large quantity of data and run routines to evaluate performance. I discovered saving a new document is much slower than expected. What's worse is that the slowness doesn't appear to be from the mongodb side or disk side, it's in nodejs.

To illustrate this problem, I created this script:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
    assert      = require('assert');


var docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    content:    String,
    createdAt:  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
var Doc = mongoose.model('Doc', docSchema);


describe('mongoose test', function () {

    before(function (done) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test?connectTimeoutMS=2000');
        done();
    });

    after(function (done) {
        mongoose.disconnect(function () {
            done();
        });
    });

    var _docCollect = function (counter, idx, batch, total, done) {
        return function (err, doc_) {
            assert(!err);
            counter.count++;
            if (counter.count === total)
                done();
        };
    };

    var _insertDocSample = function (batch, total) {
        return function (done) {
            this.timeout(10000);
            var counter = {'count': 0};
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                var doc = new Doc({
                    content: 'x'
                });
                doc.save(_docCollect(counter, i, batch, total, done));
            }
        };
    };

    describe('inserting doc data', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            var total = 500;
            it('should insert sample pass:' + i + ', count:' + total, _insertDocSample(i, total));
        }
    });

});
```

It's designed to run with mocha: `$ mocha test.js`. And the following is sample output from my laptop:

```
mongoose test
inserting doc data
  ✓ should insert sample pass:0, count:500 (1436ms)
  ✓ should insert sample pass:1, count:500 (784ms)
  ✓ should insert sample pass:2, count:500 (692ms)
  ✓ should insert sample pass:3, count:500 (662ms)
  ✓ should insert sample pass:4, count:500 (747ms)
  ✓ should insert sample pass:5, count:500 (662ms)
......
```

The script has 2 loops, the outer one runs for 50 times and the inner one 500 times. Each inner loop creates and saves a new document. When this script is running, I'm seeing the `node` process using 100% of CPU, while `mongodb` uses 11% in Activity Monitor. How come node is so busy running this script?

I also tried simple profiling like `mocha --prof`, and discovered nothing inside the script taking this much time.